# GCP BigQuery: create paritioined table paritioned by column int64 seconds by HOUR

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning, create-table

while the functions works as it should

```
SELECT 
     TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( 1614010493955 ) , HOUR) AS ts_trunc 
#-- 2021-02-22 16:00:00 UTC
```

It is not working in the context of partitioning by such a (int64) column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 
proj.data.sample_part
PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( TimeSeconds ) , HOUR)
#--
```

fails with

```
PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), a DATE column, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR), or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>]))
```

strictly is requires e.g. an already timestamp defined column <timestamp_column> but a function to convert any int64 based column should be fine.

---

The original column is int64 but RANGE_BUCKET is not so good (because I have to define the ranges myself ..)

-> The partition should be on the date more precise date/hour

Comment: What is your question? The error message very clearly shows you the options you have available.

Comment: Like stated the transformation into such a format e.g. ´TIMESTAMP_MILLIS( TimeSeconds )´ should work

Comment: What do you want? A partitioning by date? or by integer range?